# Remove /en prefix from url | nextjs 13 app directory

Tags: i18next, next.js13, next-i18next

I'm usign i18next app directory and i'm wondoring if there is an option to remove language prefix from url

##### My goal

to have url like this

- `en` for home page `example.com`
- `en` for login page `example.com/login`
- `fr` for home page `example.com`
- `fr` for login page `example.com/login`

##### My environment:

- nextjs 13.4.1 app directory
- i18next : ^22.4.15
- next-i18next": "^13.2.2"

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you could try this flow:

- `en` for home page `example.com`
- `en` for login page `example.com/login`
- `fr` for home page `example.com/fr`
- `fr` for login page `example.com/fr/login`

And i found an example for this (nextjs 13, use app dir) and im using it, its work:
https://carlogino.com/blog/nextjs13-i18n

Hope this help!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your blog link is great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at rewrite something like:

```
if (locale === DEFAULT_LOCALE) {
  return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL(`${locale}${pathname}`, request.url));
}
```